# Nativescript canvas

Tags: javascript, xml, nativescript

can anyone tell me how canvas is created in nativescript? I would like something like this

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sheet');
canvas.isDrawingMode = true;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.width = 30;
canvas.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#000000";
```

```css
#sheet {
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="sheet" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

found at http://jsfiddle.net/B525t/52/ that works on android and ois.

Thank you

Comment: Try this plugin https://github.com/triniwiz/nativescript-canvas-plugin - I am currently trying to use vue-nativescript from this repo.

Answer (score 4):

See https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-canvas, which is a proof-of-concept implementation of the `<canvas>` element for NativeScript apps. Look in the `test` folder for a small little example of the implementation in use. If you have any feedback about the component try the [repo’s issues tab](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-canvas/issues).

Comment: Thank you TJ, but I keep on getting the following error when I run the android package inside the test file using the command prompt: "Unable to install dependencies. Make sure your package.json is valid and all dependencies are correct. Error is: nativescript-canvas@0.0.1 prepublish: `node prepackage.js`
Exit status 1."  Can you help me resolve it? I have tried without any success.